# Logging individual fields of jax-rs request

Tags: jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS service with a lot of APIs to modify and retrieve data about an organization. I also have a logging filter, which logs all the requests and responses. Now I introduced sensitive data, which cannot be logged as is, so some kind of obfuscation of values has to be done.

Basically, my new request looks like this:

```
class SetImportantDataRequest {

  String field1;

  @SensitiveData
  String field2;
}
```

The current request is without `@SensitiveData` annotation. And current filter just takes the entire entity stream and converts it to a byte array and prints out as a UTF_8 string. So the log output has this line:

```
field1: whateverValue, field2: whateverValue2
```

I want the new log output be this:

```
field1: whateverValue, field2: ****
```

And the pseudo-code for doing this will be somewhere in a filter/writerInceptor/messageBodyWriter (not sure yet, need your help on this):

```
if (field has annotation SensitiveData) {
  log.info("****");
} else {
  log.info(field.getValue());
}
```

So far I was thinking in the direction of getting the stream in the request filter, somehow building the request from that stream (at least the current registered messageBodyWriter does that, so I should be able to replicate that behavior), and as for what type of object to build I think I get from the `ResourceInfo` injected into the filter. If you think this is the right approach, then I would ask how can I re-use the existing message writing capabilities to convert the stream to the request object?

Comment: Does this help? https://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jersey-custom-logging-request-and-response-entities-using-filter/

Comment: @TarunLalwani, I already have the request logging almost exactly as in the referenced post. The problem is getting the annotations from the stream. I guess I covered all the details in the question.

Comment: If you provide a minimal git repo, I might be able to provide you a solution